# How to create a button link in html which will take you to a different section of the same page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to make a button which when clicked will take you to a different section of the same page but not a different page. The button will take you to the particular section of the same page instead of you scrolling down the page.

Comment: Actually there are many blog post about this subject, Try to search before posting a question next time . https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/jump-link-same-page

Comment: <a href="#yourDivId">Go To Some Div</a>

Answer (score 0):

For example, on your home page, there is an About Us section and you want the visitors to go to the About Us section by clicking a button/link. You can set the id in your About Us section. Like this :

```
<div id="about">This is About Us Section<div>
```

And can use this link :

```
<a href="#about"></a>
```

For smooth scrolling behaviour you can set :

```
html { scroll-behavior: smooth;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for scrollTo() method

Using JavaScript, to scroll to specified coordinates:

```
function scrollWin() {

  window.scrollTo(h{int}, y{int});
}
```

And the button looks likes:

```
<button onclick="scrollWin()">Scroll to {Section}</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Button not Link as you write then you can add the button in form element with url to the same page and the anchor, as in the code example below.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form method="get" action="#anchor">
            <button type="submit">Button</button>
        </form>

        <div style="height:900px;"></div>
        <p id="anchor">Paragraph 1</p>
        <div style="height:900px;"></div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```